# How to render array of array of objects in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a an array like:

```
[
  a: [
    {
      "id" : "1"
      "val" : "sharedVal1"
    },
    {
      "id" : "2"
      "val" : "sharedVal1"
    },
  ]
  b: [
    {
      "id" : "3"
      "val" : "sharedVal2"
    },
    {
      "id" : "4"
      "val" : "sharedVal2"
    },
  ]
  c: [
    ...
  ]
]
```

How can I render this in Jade? My current attempt looks like

```
  each city in cities
    h2 asdf
    each foo in city
      .col-md-4
        .row.bottomPadding
          .col-md-3
            img(src='#{foo.logo_image_url}')
          .col-md-9.text-nowrap
            p.nav.hide-overflow #{foo.name}
```

Nothing is rendering currently. If I just pass in the flattened (un-preprocessed) array and do a single `each x in y`, it renders fine.

Comment: post how you are supplying jade with the data. your gulp/grunt config or how you are calling the api

Comment: @Daniel_L updated the OP.

Comment: "If I just pass in the flattened (un-preprocessed) array" how are you doing this, post your code

Comment: Your "array" is not valid; you're using a mixed object notation and array structure here, which probably isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating over an object, you need to use the `each key, value in obj` notation:

```
each key, city in cities
  h2 asdf
  each foo in city
    .col-md-4
      .row.bottomPadding
        .col-md-3
          img(src=foo.logo_image_url)
        .col-md-9.text-nowrap
          p.nav.hide-overflow= foo.name
```