# Render array of objects in Jade / Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I don't find a lot of stuff for Pug / Jade templating, so I try here.
I've been reading the documentation for iterations and also this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880613/how-to-render-array-of-array-of-objects-in-jade).

I'm working with Node.js, Express, and pug. So far I have some function server side that collect some data about users (I'm building a fake dating website as a school project)
So my code server side looks like this :

```
router.post('/matchaSearch', function (req, res) {
  matchaSearch(pool, session.uniqueID)
     .then((results) => {

       res.results = JSON.stringify(results)
       console.log('result', results)
       res.render('./userMatch', {res})
       })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.error('error', err)
       res.status(500).send("we don't have any suggestions for you so far")
       })
     })
```

I can log `results` in iterm and all my data is here, but when it comes to client side it's kinda different.

```
h1
 |Here are your suggestions
script.
 console.log(!{res.results}[0].username)
ul
  for username in res.results
    li= username
```

Here I can log the first username from `res.results` in my browser's console, but in my page my li is rendering :

Here are your suggestions

.[

.{

."

.i

.d

."

.:

.3

.3

can you understand my problem here ? 
it's showing every char from my array of objects.
I just wanted to show the username as a link so I can display a suggestion page with some suggested users.

I was wondering if maybe I can use jquery to render so html into my li and then call it but I'm facing a wall here as well. 
Any help is more than welcome ! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`{res}` does not make any sense to javascript. you should provide template an object include key/value pairs:

```
res.render('./userMatch', {results: results})
```

and then your loop in template becames:

```
ul
  for item in results
    li= item.username
```

Comment: This is working ! Great thank you. You've just helped 5 other people at school. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

```
    h1
     |Here are your suggestions
    script.
     console.log(!{res.results}[0].username)
    ul
      for username in res.results
        li= username.username
```

i think username is object and you are printing that whole

Comment: This is printing only empty li blank, it renders dots as many dots as char in my objets

Comment: remove this JSON.stringify(results) This is stringifying your array of objects and in jage res.results is considered as char array

Comment: This is returning me `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in my pug page. But I come it can be undefined since I can log the variable in Iterm before ?

Comment: try passing results variable instead of res and try console.log result.length in js file

Comment: The solution from dNitro is working for me. The problem was on the server side. My data wasn't sent properly, I had to use `{results: results}`