# I would like to show the items from a SQL Server database with app.js as select-option on the jade page,

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to show the items from a SQL Server database with app.js as select-option on the jade page, but even though I have reached the number of items in the list, I get the result as either [object, object] or I can only display it as a number.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../config/db');
var sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();
var result;
var liste = [];

router.get('/doktorkayit', function (req, res, next) {

    sql.connect(db, function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query('select hastaneAdi from hastaneİsimleri', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
            }

            sql.close();
            res.render('doktorkayit', {
                liste: result.recordset
            }, function (err, html) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else
                    res.send(html);
            });
        });
    });
});

select#drGorevliOlduguHastane.custom- 
select(name='drGorevliOlduguHastane')
option(value="Seçiniz" selected='seçiniz') Seçiniz
-each item in liste
option(value="") item
```

Comment: Please include the related portion of the pug template

Comment: I think this question is likely related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856146/render-array-of-objects-in-jade-pug

Answer (score 0):

I finally did.

```
res.render('doktorkayit', {
result: result.recordset
}, function (err, html) {
if (err)
console.log(err);
else
res.send(html);
});


-for item in result
option=item.hastaneAdi
```